# Embedded Linux: Which machine directory to pick in /arch/arm?

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, embedded, arm

I am just starting out with embedded Android drivers, so any help would be great. I haven't found a lot of resources online.

At the moment, I am working through a tutorial on porting a driver, and the instructions read:

> copy the platform data initialization files, “driver_sources/platform.c" and "driver_sources/platform.h" into “/arch/arm/”

How do I know which machine directory I should choose? I am using the APQ8064 DragonBoard. I don't see an APQ8064 to choose, but maybe it is called something else?

```
boot
common
configs
include
Kconfig
Kconfig.debug
Kconfig-nommu
kernel
lib
mach-at91
mach-bcmring
mach-clps711x
mach-cns3xxx
mach-davinci
mach-dove
mach-ebsa110
mach-ep93xx
mach-exynos
mach-footbridge
mach-gemini
mach-h720x
mach-highbank
mach-imx
mach-integrator
mach-iop13xx
mach-iop32x
mach-iop33x
mach-ixp2000
mach-ixp23xx
mach-ixp4xx
mach-kirkwood
mach-ks8695
mach-l7200
mach-lpc32xx
mach-mmp
mach-msm
mach-mv78xx0
mach-mxs
mach-netx
mach-nomadik
mach-omap1
mach-omap2
mach-orion5x
mach-picoxcell
mach-pnx4008
mach-prima2
mach-pxa
mach-realview
mach-rpc
mach-s3c2410
mach-s3c2412
mach-s3c2440
mach-s3c24xx
mach-s3c64xx
mach-s5p64x0
mach-s5pc100
mach-s5pv210
mach-sa1100
mach-shark
mach-shmobile
mach-spear3xx
mach-spear6xx
mach-tegra
mach-u300
mach-ux500
mach-versatile
mach-vexpress
mach-vt8500
mach-w90x900
mach-zynq
Makefile
mm
net
nwfpe
oprofile
perfmon
plat-iop
plat-mxc
plat-nomadik
plat-omap
plat-orion
plat-pxa
plat-s3c24xx
plat-s5p
plat-samsung
plat-spear
plat-versatile
tools
vfp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [elinux.org](http://elinux.org/APQ8064_MDP) this should be `mach-msm` folder. It is a folder for Qualcomm SoCs.

Comment: Thanks this is the right one. Thanks for citing your source I have bookmarked it